# Prove that $f(x) = 2x + 1$ is continuous in $p = 1$ using the $\delta - \epsilon$ definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I am learning the Delta - Epsilon definition, and got stuck in the first example. Maybe some of you can give me some light.

As in the title, I have to prove that $f(x) = 2x + 1$ is continuous in $p = 1$. So far I got that $|x| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and then the book states that "Given $\epsilon > 0$ and taking $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ we have: $1 - \delta < x < 1 + \delta \rightarrow f(1) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(1) + \epsilon$, then $f$ is continuous in $p = 1$."

I just don't understand why it takes $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and why the last statement proves $f$ is in fact continuous in $1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of continuity in a point using epsilon-delta? If you understand the definition, this example is very clear.

Comment: "In p=  1"?  There is no "p" in the formula.  Did you mean "at x= 1"?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's supposed to denote the point x = 1. I used "p" because I quickly copied from the book without paying much attention.

Answer (score 2):

Your thoughts, I can see, are all over the place. Time to start over, and to move ***SLOWLY***. The only way you will ever learn to do this if you do it very slowly, making sure to understand both *why* and *how* you are making each step.

---

By definition, $f$ is continuous at $1$ if:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon$.

So, we are proving a statement that begins with "for every $\epsilon>0$. Therefore, our proof will start with the typical:

**Let $\epsilon > 0$**.

Now, we need to find some $\delta>0$ such that a condition will be met. That is, as long as we can choose one $\delta$, we are done. But which $\delta$ to pick?
 Well, the condition we need to meet is:

$$|f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon$$

Well, write the left expression out and we get

$$|f(x)-f(1)| = |2x-1 - (2\cdot 1 - 1)| = |2x-1-2+1=2(x-1)|=2|x-1|$$

So, what we really need to meet is the condition:

$$2|x-1|<\epsilon$$

and at the same time, we can still choose a $\delta$ and demand that $|x-1|<\delta$. Well, we can see that if $|x-1|<\frac\epsilon2$, then $2|x-1|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, if we set $\delta=\frac\epsilon2$, then we **know** that if $|x-1|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon$. OMG, we did it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just want to clarify, when you substituted the f(x) in the |f(x) - f(1)| < epsilon inequality, why did you used 2x - 1 as opposed to 2x + 1?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$
|f(y)-f(x)|\leq 2\cdot |y-x|
$$
Then given a $\epsilon>0$ we set $\delta=\epsilon/2$ and we have 
\begin{align}
|y-x|<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2} 
\implies &
2\cdot |y-x|<2\cdot \delta={\epsilon}
\\
\implies &
 |2y-2x|<2\cdot \delta={\epsilon}
\\
\implies &
 |2y+1-2x-1|<2\cdot \delta={\epsilon}
\\
\implies &
 |f(y)-f(x)|<2\cdot \delta={\epsilon}
\\
\end{align}